# Cannot pass the form data to a method in order to validate form

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm trying to create a custom validator for one field in the AddSongForm. I used the inline validator and it uses two methods from my Songs class. When I try running the code, I get the following trace back:

```
form = AddSongForm()
[2017-05-16 13:44:11,547] ERROR in app: Exception on /addsong [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 228, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:/Users/Pellissari/Desktop/files/projects/Musical 9gag/view.py", line 40, in addsong
if form.validate_on_submit():
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf\form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 310, in validate
return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\form.py", line 152, in validate
if not field.validate(self, extra):
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 204, in validate
stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
File "C:\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py", line 224, in _run_validation_chain
validator(form, self)
File "C:\Users\Pellissari\Desktop\files\projects\app\forms.py", line 20, in validate_song_link
if Songs.get_provider(url) in valid_providers:
TypeError: get_provider() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2017 13:44:11] "POST /addsong HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This is my form class

```
class AddSongForm(Form):
    song_title = StringField('song_title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    song_artist = StringField('song_artist', validators=[DataRequired()])
    song_genre = StringField('song_genre')
    song_link = StringField('song_link', validators=[DataRequired()])

    def validate_song_link(form, song_link):
    valid_providers = ['youtube.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'soundcloud.com', 'www.soundcloud.com']
    url = song_link.data
    if Songs.get_provider(url) in valid_providers:
        if Songs.get_embed_code(url) is not False:
            return True
        else:
            print("couldn't get your content")
            return False
    else:
        print("unsupported provider")
        return False
```

And here is the class I used the methods

```
class Songs(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    artist = db.Column(db.String(30))
    genre = db.Column(db.String(40))
    author = db.Column(db.String(40))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    likes_num = db.Column(db.Integer)
    song_link = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def get_provider(self, url):
        return urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)[1]

    def get_embed_code(self, url):
        code = None
        vars = {'url': url, 'format': 'json', 'iframe': 'true', 'maxwidth': '450', 'show_comments': 'false'}
        provider = self.get_provider(url)
        endpoint = "http://"+provider+"/oembed?"
        source = endpoint+urllib.parse.urlencode(vars)
        try:
            request = urlopen(source)
            code = json.load(request)['html']
            return code
        except:
            print("impossible to get your content. Check the link") 
            return False
```

I'm quite new with Python and this is my first time writing OO code, so I have no idea what could be happening here. Besides the problem, I would be happy if you also could give me some feedback on the code and if there are room to improve in some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not convinced these should be methods on Songs. They don't refer to anything to do with the Song class.

However if you want to keep them as methods, but still want to call them from the class, they need to be classmethods, not instance methods.

```
@classmethod
def get_provider(cls, url):
    return urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)[1]

@classmethod
def get_embed_code(cls, url):
    ...
    provider = cls.get_provider(url)
```

Comment: I use them inside another method to add a new attribute to a Song object, thats why I put them inside the Songs. I can use them also to make the validation, keeping the DRY principle.  
In your opinion, should I transform them in regular functions and call them when needed in my code?

Answer (score 1):

First of all correct the indentation for the method `validate_song_link`. It should be like this:

```
def validate_song_link(form, song_link):
    valid_providers = ['youtube.com', 'www.youtube.com', 'soundcloud.com', 'www.soundcloud.com']
    url = song_link.data
    if Songs.get_provider(url) in valid_providers:
        if Songs.get_embed_code(url) is not False:
            return True
        else:
            print("couldn't get your content")
            return False
    else:
        print("unsupported provider")
        return False
```

To solve your problem you can try to change the `get_provider` method to a class method like this:

```
@classmethod
def get_provider(cls, url):
    return urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)[1]
```

And then you can call this way:

```
songs = Songs()

if Songs.get_provider(songs, url) in valid_providers:
    if Songs.get_embed_code(url) is not False:
        return True
```